# Behavior of .on().on() vs. only one .on()

Tags: event-handling, jquery

I want to catch "*inward*" type events and do **ABC**, and catch "*outward*" type events to do **XYZ**. I'm getting problems with the various events firing at weird times that I didn't expect, so I'm wondering if my approach is actually causing the problem.

```
<div class="box">first box</div>
<div class="box">second box</div>

$(".box")
  .on("focus mouseover mousedown", function(){ /* do ABC */ })
  .on("blur mouseout mouseup",     function(){ /* do XYZ */ });
```

I think that stringing the `.on()` methods together like this makes sure that the blur event is only triggered for that same `.box`. But other than that, I expect it behaves identically to if I did it this way:

```
$(".box").on("focus mouseover mousedown", function(){ /* do ABC */ });
$(".box").on("blur mouseout mouseup",     function(){ /* do XYZ */ });
```

or doing something like this: *(which seems redundant)*

```
$(".box").on({
  focus:     function(){   /* do ABC */ },
  mouseover: function(){   /* do ABC */ },
  mousedown: function(){   /* do ABC */ },

  blur:      function(){   /* do XYZ */ },
  mouseout:  function(){   /* do XYZ */ },
  mouseup:   function(){   /* do XYZ */ }
);
```

I'm not asking "which is better" but rather, "how are they different"? They seem to be getting different results.

Comment: They're all about the same. on returns the receiver.

Comment: No, they are not different. How can we possibly post that as an answer? it's too short.

Comment: For such questions, you should keep [this](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) in your bookmarks.

Comment: Edited the question. Maybe I have some bad assumptions here.

Comment: Why the downvotes on this question? Seems like a valid stackoverflow question to me.

Comment: Is it really so bad that someone came to the world's largest collection of smart programmers to ask a programming question? Someone needed help, and they got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're different in the sense that your jQuery selector `$(".box")` only runs once, so chaining them is more efficient.  Functionally they're identical.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery function calls return the selector-matched context of `this`, allowing chaining.

Because of this, your `.on()` chain will work as you intend.